# PyPDF2 error - PyPDF2.utils.PdfStreamError: Stream has ended unexpectedly

Tags: pdf, merge, pypdf

I am Python newbie and wrote a script about a year back to retrieve pdf files and merge them into a single file/book. The script works and does what I need it to do, but lately as I am no longer the only user there seems to be some files that I think are causing it to crash. My suspicion is that it may be newer pdf files that have higher resolution images or forms etc. that PyPDF2 may not be able to handle, but I don't know that for sure. One thing that would help to know is what file(s) is creating the issue to scan the files, instead of using the native pdf file, but I can't figure that out since the error occurs upon the writing of all files. Below is the snippet of my code that I use for merging them along with the error. Is pyPDF2 still being updated? Is there are better supported/commercial utility out there that can do this? Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    for f in Submittal_Files:        
        h_path, f_name = os.path.split(f) 
        outfile.append(open(f, 'rb'))
        
    outfile.write(open(Final_Submittal_File_Name + ".pdf", 'wb'))
    print("\nSUCCESSFULLY COMPLETED!")
    print("PRESS ENTER TO END!")
    program_holder = input()
    break
```

Sorry about the long error log before. I won't be able to get the files until Monday 7/23 when I will have access to them. I will provide 2 examples.

LOG:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymbe1tnak7uuvs7/PDF-Merge-Crash-log.txt?dl=0

File Set #1 - Large Submittal - I had to delete some files to protect the innocent. They are mostly cover pages for sections and I know those are not an issue as they are used all the time.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xavrpfxmo6dr7mb/Case%20%231%20-%20JUST%20PDFs.rar?dl=0

File Set #2 - Smaller Submittal - Same as above.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lxk8bts0w2qsx8/Case%20%232%20-%20JUST%20PDFS.rar?dl=0

Comment: Holy five-screen long error log Batman! Let's hope there is something useful in there. In the mean time, can you add a link to one of those problematic PDFs, so we can see for ourselves and test out if a solution works? Also, please remove your "any other solution" as recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow. It sounds like your question should be able to get answered within this scope.

Comment: Added files, please let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I ran some tests with convert on my ubuntu machine and that seemed to work and I think it is the forms/links that may be causing the problem for pyPDF2, so I am going to try and run pyPDF2 on linux to do the merge and see if works as well if not, I will use convert as a band-aid, since I can't get it to work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Is PyPDF2 still being updated?

I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2 and pypdf.

PyPDF2 has received a lot of upgrades in 2022. I now merged the pypdf and PyPDF2 projects back into `pypdf`. So `pypdf` is the way to go.

PyPDF2 will no longer receive updates.

The error you described could be due to a broken PDF document. Without the specific document, it's impossible to tell.